# Other contacts has shattered video feed on skype

Tags: video, skype

When I speak to my contacts on Skype the video feed I get from them is shattered into parts...

[image]

I am using Windows 7, and the latest Skype (I believe 6.3). This started after an update on Skype.

I tried reinstalling Skype without any success...

Anyone had a similar problem and solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Reinstall the operating system and then Skype on it.